# Prove that Px1*Px = Px1, and Mx1*Mx = Mx

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection-matrices

Consider the following linear regression model:
y = Xβ + u = X1β1 + X2β2 + u

where y and u are n × 1 vectors, X1 and X2 are n × k1 and n × k2
matrices of explanatory variables.

Define the following projections
PX1 = X1 (X1^T X1)^(−1)X1^T and MX1 = In − PX1

PX2 = X2 (X2^T X2)−1 X2^T, and MX2 = In − PX2

Prove that: Px1*Px = Px1, and Mx1*Mx = Mx

I understand this intuitively- ie. the expressions make sense, but I cannot for the life of me mathematically prove it. Any help would be v much appreciated.

Comment: MathJax, please.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Math SE. Please format the equations using MathJax. You may use the following tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference